# Event on slot modification

Tags: events, clips

I wonder if in CLIPS I can associate an event on a slot's modification.
Example:

```
(defclass ROOM (is-a USER)
    (slot id
        (type SYMBOL))
    (slot windows-status
        (allowed-strings "open" "close")))
```

When 'windows-status' changes in value, I'd like to call some function, according to the allowed-strings.

Thank you,
Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a before, after, or around message-handler for the put- method of the slot and you can call a function from the message-handler based on the value.

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(defclass ROOM (is-a USER)
  (slot id
    (type SYMBOL))
  (slot windows-status
    (allowed-strings "open" "close")))
CLIPS>     
(defmessage-handler ROOM put-id before (?value)
  (printout t "put-id event " ?self:id crlf))
CLIPS> 
(defmessage-handler ROOM put-windows-status before (?value)
  (printout t "put-window-status event " ?self:windows-status crlf))
CLIPS> (make-instance [r1] of ROOM (id room1) (windows-status "open"))
put-id event nil
put-window-status event nil
[r1]
CLIPS> (send [r1] put-id room2)
put-id event room1
room2
CLIPS> (send [r1] put-windows-status "close")
put-window-status event open
"close"
CLIPS>
```